# How to click element on pseudo element ::after in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

[image]

I would like to Click button at ::after but I don't know how to create xpath from pseudo element

I try this way //em[@class='x-btn-split']::after but it's not work.

Please anyone help.

Comment: Pseudo elements are not part of XPath data model. You can select the `button` element referencing its `@id` or `span` child string value.

Comment: The @id is generate id button and span is not my point to click. I would like to click the dropdownlist at ::after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly id='ext-gen33'. But if you want xpath only then include 2 attribute if there are many matching buttons
xpath = //button[@type='button' and @id='ext-gen33'].

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code/custom keyword which takes css of the element you want to click as input and perform the click on that element

```
Click Psuedo Element Using Javascript   
    [Arguments]  ${elem} 

    ${click_elem}   Remove String Using Regexp  ${elem}  css[=:]  
    ${ele}    Execute Javascript  return document.querySelector(arguments[0]);  ARGUMENTS   ${click_elem}  
    ${clickable}    Execute Javascript  return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();    ARGUMENTS   ${ele}  
    ${cx}    Execute Javascript    return arguments[0].x   ARGUMENTS    ${clickable}  
    ${cy}    Execute Javascript    return arguments[0].y   ARGUMENTS    ${clickable}  
    Execute Javascript   document.elementFromPoint(${cx}, ${cy}).click();
```